# Best way to create file in non existing directory

Tags: c++, file, boost-filesystem

What is the possibly best way to create a new file in C++ in a given path, if I cannot assume that the directories leading to that path aren't there yet.

For example I wanted to create the file `I:\Documents\Directory\SubDir\SubSubDir\MyFile.txt`, but the directories `SubDir` and `SubSubDir` aren't there yet. Hence I have to create them beforehand.

I'm allowed to use the library `boost::filesystem` for this purpose. Does boost::filesystem contain such functions?

**Edit**

After reading the boost::filesystem documentation I found the relatively simple answer to my question.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    try {
        boost::filesystem::path dirPath("I:\\Documents\\Directory\\SubDir\\SubSubDir\\MyFile.txt");
        boost::filesystem::create_directories(dirPath.parent_path());
    }
    catch(const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& err) {
        std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note it's now part of the `std::filesystem` (c++17 if fully implemented in your compiler... it came latetly)

Answer (score 4):

It's all in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directory).

You can safely *always* use `create_directory` and/or `create_directories`:

> Creation failure because `p` [the path] resolves to an existing directory shall not be treated as an error.

Comment: Many thanks. How can I extract the directory part of a given path?

In my case  `I:\Documents\Directory\SubDir\SubSubDir\ `

Comment: ... and that is also in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-decomposition). I don't see a relation with your current question, maybe you should ask a new one. Make sure to read the documentation first (that probably lead to your question being downvoted).